# Maven is not replacing as i expected

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

I have defined some profiles at pom.xml in order to make a resource mapping deppending of the OS. It worked at first time (a week ago), but now after a git clone, it stoped work.

This is my pom.xml profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>windows</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>dos</family>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <file.mapping>file:///C:/software/photos/</file.mapping>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>
```

This is the line in where i have troubles:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/photos/*" location="@file.mapping@"></mvc:resources>
```

This is the "raw" line, i dont have troubles with it. It works fine:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/photos/*" location="file:///C:/software/photos/"></mvc:resources>
```

It seems to do a replacement, there is no trouble with maven install and all that. But the first line dont work. Idk whats happening here. In Linux works fine.

Comment: What *exactly* does not work?

Comment: When i make a get petition, it doesn't return a jpg. With the "raw line" it works, but the good line doesnt return it.